# How do I get the selected option from a combobox to display the information from that option in the next page in text boxes?

Tags: database, vba, vb.net, ms-access

Sorry, quite difficult to word.
I'm coding a 'surgery database' for a school project and have got so far as to program the login page, which works successfully from the database, and I have coded the directory. The directory combobox displays patients from the database and this functions correctly, but I do not know how to get it so that when you press search, it opens up my main.vb page and fills the textboxes with the correct data from the access database, based upon which patient was selected.

Massive thanks to anyone who can help.

I'm on VB using microsoft access which I haven't really used before. I've tried following tutorials but everything seems slightly different and doesn't get the desired results.

```
Private Sub BtnPatient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPatient.Click
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDB WHERE [Name] = " & TxtPatient.Text & "'", myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader


    Me.Visible = False
    Me.Hide()
    Main.ShowDialog()
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

The output should be the patients details from the access database.

Comment: You are missing the `'` before the name

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Answer (score 0):

You're a student so I'm going to keep this as simple as possible without trying to insult your intelligence.  If I do, please forgive me in advance.

There are much better ways to do what I'm about to explain but this will work.

The database code should be in the Open event of your main form.  You need to pass the value of TxtPatient.Text to the main form in the Tag property.  Here's how to do that:

On your search page:

```
Private Sub BtnPatient_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPatient.Click
    Dim fMain As New main
    fMain.Tag = Txtpatient.Text
    fMain.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Now, in the open event of your main form should be something akin to this:

```
Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDB WHERE [Name] = '" & Me.Tag & "'", myConnection)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            Do While dr.Read
                Me.txtName = dr("PatientName")
                Me.txtDOB = dr("DateOfBirth")
                'etc...
            Loop
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("There are no records.")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Pay special attention to the "Select" statement. You should see where I replaced txtPatient.Text with Me.Tag

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't believe I just posted an answer on a question that's almost 5 years old.  I'm going to bed.